# Getting Security exception while trying to fetch networkcapabilities on android 11

Tags: android, exception, android-source, android-connectivitymanager, android-app-ops

I am getting SecurityException followed by RemoteException while trying to access below code. API

> val networkCapabilities =
> connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)

Exception getting

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 10319
           at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2385)
           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2294)
           at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkCapabilities(IConnectivityManager.java:3347)
           at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(ConnectivityManager.java:1549)

Caused by android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage(AppOpsManager.java:7783)
        at com.android.server.ConnectivityService.getNetworkCapabilities(ConnectivityService.java:2297)
        at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IConnectivityManager.java:1357)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

I have analyzed it and when I dig into the aosp code, I got the flow is going to **checkPackage** method of from AppOpsManager class shown in attached screenshot and from the code we know whenever check package condition is not equal to MODE_ALLOWED then only we will get Security Excception. But I don't have any. Idea when that condition will fail.

Please help me if anyone has any idea on this , thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in the manifest?

Comment: Yes @sdex we have this permission

Comment: @Sudhansu, got any workaround for this ?

Comment: @Anukoolsrivastav no, not yet

Answer (score 20):

Looks like it is a known issue
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175055271

```
Dec 10, 2020 11:43AM
We have passed this to the development team and will update this issue with more information as it becomes available.
```

```
Sep 14, 2021 12:04AM
Marked as fixed.
The issue has been fixed in Android S and above.
```

But no fixes for Android below S.

Comment: Latest comment on 13th Sept 2021 shows that Google marked it fixed in Android 12.